# C socket recv function returning undefined error (errno)

Tags: python, c, sockets, errno

I am trying to make a file transfer program. I am currently programming the C server and using a short Python script as the client. When I try sending the filename from Python to C, the recv function (in C) returns an undefined error. It has received half of the filename once. Here is the code:
C server (problematic recv function is pointed out):

```
#define BUFFER 2000000
#define HEADERSIZE 20
#define PORT 9342
#define FGET "FGET"
#define UPLD "UPLD"

typedef struct timeval timeval_t;

int i;
fd_set readlist, sockets;

void* sendf(void* sock){
  printf("File Descriptor: %d\n", *(int*)sock);
  fflush(stdout);
  char* filename = (char*) malloc(21*sizeof(char));
  ssize_t result = recv(*(int*)sock, filename, 20+1, 0);
  if (result != 0){
    printf("%s", strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
  }
  printf("Filename: ");
  puts(filename);
  FILE* sfile = fopen(filename, "rb");
  free(filename);
  fseek(sfile, 0, SEEK_END);
  unsigned long long filesize = ftell(sfile);
  fseek(sfile, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char* content = malloc(BUFFER);
  for(i=0; i<=ceil(filesize/BUFFER); ++i){
    if (filesize >= BUFFER){
      fread(content, BUFFER, 1, sfile);
      filesize-=BUFFER;
      fseek(sfile, filesize-1, SEEK_END);
    } else{
      fread(content, filesize, 1, sfile);
    }
    content = realloc(content, BUFFER);
  }
  fclose(sfile);
  char* header = malloc(HEADERSIZE);
  sprintf(header, "%20llu", filesize);
  send(*(int*)sock, header, 20, 0);
  send(*(int*)sock, content, filesize, 0);
  free(filename);
  free(content);
  free(header);
  return NULL;
}

void* receivef(void* sock){
  printf("Function not written yet");
  return NULL;
}

int main(){

  chdir("/Users/reimeytal/Desktop/Fileserver");
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  pthread_t thread;
  timeval_t timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 1;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in server;
  server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  FD_ZERO(&sockets);
  FD_SET(sock, &sockets);
  bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
  listen(sock, 5);
  int maxsock = sock;
  int clientsock;
  char* msghdr = (char*) malloc(5*sizeof(char));
  while (1){
    readlist = sockets;
    select(FD_SETSIZE, &readlist, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    for(i=0; i<=maxsock; i++){
      if(FD_ISSET(i, &readlist)){
        if(i==sock){
          clientsock = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
          FD_SET(clientsock, &sockets);
          if(clientsock>sock){
            maxsock = clientsock;
          }
        } else{
          printf("Incoming message from %d\n", i);
          fflush(stdout);
          recv(i, msghdr, 5, 0);
          clientsock = i;
          if(strcmp(msghdr, FGET) == 0){
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, sendf, (int *)&clientsock);
          }/*else if(strcmp(msghdr, UPLD) == 0){
            pthread_create(&thread, NULL, receivef, (int*)&i);
          }else{
            puts("ERROR: Received invalid message header");
          }*/
          msghdr = (char *) realloc(msghdr, 5*sizeof(char));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
```

Result when running:

```
Incoming message from 4
File Descriptor: 4
Incoming message from 4
Incoming message from 4
Undefined error: 0
```

Python client:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(("localhost", 9342))
sock.send(b'FGET\0')
sock.send(b'abcdeftghijklmno.txt\0')
```

If anyone needs my to clarify/add something, I'd be happy to do so. Thanks

Comment: I compiled and executed and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake here:

```
ssize_t result = recv(*(int*)sock, filename, 20+1, 0);
  if (result != 0){
    printf("%s", strerror(errno));
    exit(0);
  }
```

`recv` returns the number of bytes written, so you should check `if (result <= 0)`.

You are getting a result code 0 because the Python app closed the connection after sending the data. Apart from that all should work.

EDIT: Removed part about timing issue that was incorrect.

Comment: VG but the timing issue you mention is imaginary. TCP will deliver all the data sent before the closure.

Comment: You are right, my bad. In this case actually it seems to whole thing is working but OP is confused by the fact that the socket is closed at the end.